# Powershell Where-Object inserting array

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I'm trying to build a Powershell script that can filter the information from a CSV file. But I'm having problems when using an array as one of parameters.

This command works when I import the CSV file and type it in manually:

```
$data |
    where-object {
        (
            $_.PackageAffected -eq "BslEqipWebPkg" -or
            $_.PackageAffected -eq "BslIDealAdminPkg" -or
            $_.PackageAffected -eq "ALL"
        ) -and (
            $_.ENV -eq "PROD" -or $_.ENV -eq "ALL"
        )
    } |
    select-object -property 'major step id','minor step id','PackageAffected',ENV,detail |
    format-table -autosize
```

I am trying to build the `$_.PackageAffected` line up using an array.

Here is the code so far (that isn't working):

```
$packageList = "`$_.PackageAffected -eq `"" + $package[0] + "`" -or"
for ($element=1; $element -lt $package.count; $element++) {
    $packageList = $packageList + " `$_.PackageAffected -eq `"" + $package[$element] + "`" -or"
}
$packageList = $packageList + " `$_.PackageAffected -eq `"ALL`""

$data | 
    where-object{($packageList) -and ($_.ENV -eq $environment -or $_.ENV -eq "ALL")} |
    select-object -property 'major step id','minor step id','PackageAffected',ENV,detail |
    format-table -autosize
$packageList
```

At the bottom where I've put `$packageList` it displays onscreen the string I would expect to see, which is:

```
$_.PackageAffected -eq "pkgName1" -or $_.PackageAffected -eq "pkgName2" -or $_.PackageAffected -eq "ALL"
```

But when I view the table after it's been run, there are no filters on it for the `PackageAffected`.

My suspicions are that I've converted the command into a string and when it runs, Powershell doesn't recognise it as a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate the expression. This can be done with Invoke-Expression, e.g.

```
Invoke-Expression $packageList
```

In the context of  your code, this would be:

```
$data | 
    where-object{(Invoke-Expression $packageList) -and ($_.ENV -eq $environment -or $_.ENV -eq "ALL")} |
    select-object -property 'major step id','minor step id','PackageAffected',ENV,detail |
    format-table -autosize
```